# Why doesn't TypeScript work without explicitly specifying an argument type?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I create an application that is initialized with a configuration object:

```
interface Config<Clients, Users> {
  clients: Record<keyof Clients,(arg: {a: number, b: string}) => void>
  users: Record<keyof Users, (container: Record<keyof Clients, any>) => void>
} 

// And constructor function:
function create<Clients, Users>(_cfg: Config<Clients, Users>) {
  // ...
}
```

Now I will try to call the function with the configuration. When I declare the argument here along with the type, everything works:

```
create({
  clients: {
    test: (_arg: {a: number, b: string}) => {}, // Explicit arg type definition
  },
  users: {
    user1: (clients) => {
      clients.test // No error here 
    },
  }
})
```

But if I skip specifying a type, the "test" key just disappears from the "clients" variable:

```
create({
  clients: {
    test: (_arg) => {}, // When we declare an argument without type, the type of variable 'clients' below becomes 'Record<never, any>'
  },
  users: {
    user1: (clients) => {
      clients.test // <-- Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Record<never, any>'.
    },
  }
})
```

In a real project, the argument has many different properties (like dependency injection), so here I want to use an unpacking of the object without explicitly specifying the type:

```
create({
  clients: {
    test: ({a, b}) => { console.log(a, b) }, // <-- Want to use unpacking without explicitly specifying the type
  },
  users: {
    user1: (clients) => {
      clients.test // There is an error here 
    },
  }
})
```

Can I make TypeScript automatically understand the types of variables "a" and "b" while getting rid of the error `Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Record<never, any>'`?

Link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=3&pln=37&pc=1#code/PTAEEkDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUiD29Sq5IgJYDmArvMtEQaFgEYBWsq0AUETAiuqAMIFiJADx8ANkVgwAzgBpQAVWkJpAPlABvNqDwSp0aQC5QAJRY4AJsIDWsAJ5ZE-PTNkAKZPBLGNyY5DIAW3oEeXpjaWh4ThIAXwBKUABedQA3LCILVW1QMmV4I1NzeCtbByclFXk3fBhkTgRjM3wSm3tHZ0lXUGRIO1VElNB0zOzYtjYQfgJI%20DJWHEwySFYaSDZEZdXaVHhYKlhRFwN5SoLVNwB9VERvacJSI66TxXy1RK0dKYA6X7ZxyZgABiRAK0FAsAAHshAgAHMSweQAdxw1mkbF2%20zgbk%20umehVxOjgkWMV08d18-iCIXgYQiURiCWS6g0sXkUwA6gALKSgJEYCwsMSeDDQHk9LxBfSgHl7HpiAgkPlEMWgMWiuywxEQ1IIOximJ81HonRsnJ5FQ%20HI6C3wACMpNQx2kgxZ1p0eP00m%20xPBUwAclgIfB4ItZRh3WbTf94hMpgBlcyQCwQ6FwhHyCwEADk4JR8DRGL2BxxOSd%20KtHrVsBJoDJXldmjZoE5PMgfIFQpFPXb5KlMGVYqwZHB0E12vVavHdCcqU8RGQ9ARoGz5a92dAIQVSM35kCNZXzUswkgsF1tJ7-WzOSjuTelY9toddbXMkbhI9r4MPprfrAAAVQy1eAxxXX0NyzA9ICwcEoSISI6HbMctUPYorFPc95F6K9vkjWQbxjOMwAAFS5UEUyhGF4W1LNIFzI0C3RTES1xL8CXdKYoB6UBizEUBYVDZhWHkSc%2033AcuWQaRQECbDQAsIhEEQBBpQErBgOoA83AkWx5NgLVkykVA7FATghOoAh4nkDiwGkINwwgPlelHIMLR7XJIFhNBrENDpJwYczBy5YdYMheEiFQFUxBM6QtUixA7ENSdkNgQx3V9UlfDCJkhg0PAZiwBFvgVEgPDCRJmxvfCbXvTR3SfR1nXfd0dDYn8EKmUiVNM6TemDUNcAcvCCISCYgA)

**UPDATE:**
I made a new example showing two problems:

1. having arguments without explicitly specifying their type causes us to lose the keys of the `clients` object in `command1`
2. I have no idea how to correctly specify the type of `Config.commands` so that in `command1` each property would have a different type (`Client` or derived from it), depending on how they were declared.

[Example in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIEsCmA7ALtA3gKGtMAXNCgK4C2ARkgE7QC80ADNrtMAPYoRrUnBrtqACkLFyVagEosrPGgAWCCADow9fKwC%202bdlCQY8ZOliKQAE2hIAHmlTnDiVBhx4KRbtQQoA5uoDkykH%20LHgcXDx8AsKipJQ0ADTQ7tCe3j7SrnipJAAONCKSstAKSsoU6hRaOizedtQAZmDASHCcDQg%20ADxGzhBJsOxkZGAoDgB8MmFO6BBEAEpIHNTmXQDWSACe7A1wM2j90CJEcRJJKWm%200nSTvejjrBzDow4LS4KrG9u7g89jh0JQMYDm9lp8tjs9sDDnc0ONrpMAG7sBDmSYAenR0AA6vIwBgIPJ2CQLNAAJKpfLABANTbQbzcJBgSyQxZg9YQn77GH7SYCaBrFDsADuJXkrRszQwaE2%20XpKDYQxGYwAjAB%20GrYBokFD8BCcNjUJl2aA9bkDJUvCCTQHtTpEQYoDrdWEwy3-eFEZGoqbQTGa4BG-FIIRZIF9IhZabAlVEETnBHEJCi2GFJKY8m7YWtcxLcBG-DUHzkPpJBStAAG4dmFZKsta3mgVfd5hVtaoTyQMArbI%20XRQSERiShznGFeKGeraFjR0TA5T%20yEKsk6axZKzrSNZHYQ7FrTARZLszL4qbU4gtdy1HY%20WoaGQMAPOaQdn4SEsyyN-BAdKEFBIGDZkm75iuwED7kWj4oJswpgJsRTZH6WJTjOxxiPE1DnB4PDpHOyYjugaZIZm0BATYuSINSaA-pSSw0nS5Z1nKkIHsWZClmK%20L%20DAHQDiU7DsEc-4YBSwrEhYKD%20IBozSoJ5iCQgGCDjQDEIOxCHZFOABMcZgAm9CTPOBFoKYCAWPGyQaZoCSPC2cy%20mELaoeeiZRpp3LKChxEALIkNwyStJCMpyrCxTRn0nn7FpPl%20RgVDQEF9bGaZFjFNoeDaJokhAA)

Comment: What is the use of the `Clients` and `Users` type parameters if you're only paying attention to their keys?  I would say that you should just use the key types as type parameters directly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4pGXW) and then you'd have a better experience with inference (because the compiler won't spend any time during type inference trying to figure out what `Clients` is given only its keys).  If this meets your needs I could write up an answer when I get a chance.  If not, let me know what's wrong and I'll see if I can address it.

Comment: Hmm, your example works just as it should. I didn't even think that such a small detail could change everything so dramatically. Everything works fine, both the client keys and the argument keys are accessible.

I'll make changes to the working draft, and then answer your question. The thing is, there are a lot of other properties in the actual project that I cut out to focus on the essence. If they fit into this concept, then this solution is fine. But I won't be able to test it until about 12 hours later. I'll report back on the result then, but thank you very much already anyway.

Comment: I checked your suggestion in a working project, it works, thanks again. Could you please add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed an important point. The properties of the `clients` object are methods that should return an object of a certain type:`test: (_arg: {a: number, b: string}) => Client`. But in fact it can be any object extending the `Client` class. And when I refer to `clients.test` in method `user1`, then TS must see the real type there, not the base `Client` class. So I need not only keys in generics, but also values to map to keys. Please help with the solution.

Comment: If you edit your question to include a [mre] demonstrating the added requirement then maybe I can look at it.  Otherwise it’s just based on a text description in comments and the opportunity for confusion is too great.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I articulated the current problems and created an example to show the point. Please take a look at it, I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Now you're probably expecting more than the compiler can give you in terms of both generic type inference and callback parameter type inference for a single function parameter.  See [ms/TS#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for info.  If you can split it apart into more of a curried (fluent builder) pattern where you first pass in clients and then later commands, then you'll get better inference behavior.  Check out [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDGZVw); if that works for your needs I can write up an answer. Let me know.

Comment: Hmm, in a way, it's nice to know that it's a TS limitation after all, not my fault. However, the variant `create(...)(...)` you suggested doesn't quite fit the concept of my application. Can you tell me, is it possible to implement [a more readable variant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzGBeOAnApgQyhwAoBKAKDPmRQDpgAbJHMKCIgbwHoAqGv7zgF9ylcNTogAtpLxgAJmx58aAkRSA) using TS? Or will dynamic types get lost between method calls?

Comment: I made a [sandbox for a solution](https://tsplay.dev/mMRAkW) based on the object and methods as I would like it to look like. But, honestly, I don't understand how it should work, because we pass data in parts in separate methods and TS can't see all types at once, as it was in the initial version. Please see if this solution is possible.

Comment: Not really, no.  You could try to use [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to mutate the type of `app` after each call, but it's a lot more trouble than it's worth and requires more type annotations than the original problem you're trying to solve.  Mutations are hard to model in TypeScript.  I don't understand why fluent builders are a problem for you; you can make them a little easier to use by giving them method names like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPjXeN).

Comment: If you want any version of this as an answer I'll write it up; otherwise the answer is probably "no this is a design limitation in TypeScript" but I might not be very interested in writing up an answer if it's only that.

Comment: No, unfortunately none of the versions you suggested fit into my component API by design. And the ones I'd like to use don't fit because of TS limitations. So I can't afford to ask you to waste your time with an answer that isn't useful. I want to think more about the API, maybe I'll find another design that would be just as good as the current one, but still allow TS to do strict typing.

Comment: That's too bad. It's hard for me to see how `create({clients: {  client1: (a, b) => new Client(a),  client2: (a, b) => new ClientChild(a, b) }, commands:{ command1: (clients) => {      clients.client1; clients.client2 }}});` is desirable but the quite similar `create.clients({  client1: (a, b) => new Client(a),  client2: (a, b) => new ClientChild(a, b) }).commands({ command1: (clients) => { clients.client1; clients.client2 }});` is unacceptable.  But it's your use case and not mine, so I won't second guess you further.  Good luck to you!